# Symfony 3 with 1 vhost and 2 environments

Tags: php, apache, symfony, vhosts

I would like to test my Symfony 3 site in 2 different environments with 1 VHOST only.
Let me explain, I go through app_dev I have the module xdebug to "on" and the modules opcache and apcu to off, this is ok. I would like to pass my site in prod (so without going through app_dev) on the same vhost but with the module xdebug to off and modules apcu and opcache to on.

Is it possible? What is the best solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't. Apache virtualhosts are cheap and are not difficult to setup. Even having Xdebug installed on the machine will slow down your production environment. There is also no way to say in a single Vhost that the prod env would use a different configuration than dev.